# ¿Como puedo superponer una imagen sobre el marco de la cámara (en tiempo real)?

Tags: android, opencv

Estoy elaborando un programa de reconocimiento de objetos con opencv y android, el programa básicamente hace al momento que que la cámara en tiempo real reconoce el objeto muestra una imagen con información del objeto en forma de realidad aumentada sobre el marco de la cámara.

el problema es que muestra un error en la adición de las imágenes ¿como puedo lograr bien la adición?

Las imágenes no son del mismo tamañano.

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(Mat aInputFrame) {
    // Crear una imagen en escala de grises
    Imgproc.cvtColor(aInputFrame, grayscaleImage, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB);

    Mat imagen = Highgui.imread(ruta, Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
    Rect roi = new Rect(150, 200, 40, 60);
    MatOfRect faces = new MatOfRect();

    // Utilice el clasificador para detectar rostros
    if (cascadeClassifier != null) {
        cascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale(grayscaleImage, faces, 1.1, 2, 2,
                new Size(absoluteFaceSize, absoluteFaceSize), new Size());
    }

    Mat copia = aInputFrame.clone();
    Mat imgroi = imagen.submat(roi);
    Mat salidaroi = copia.submat(roi);

    Core.addWeighted(imgroi, 0.5, imagen, 0.2, 1,  salidaroi);

    return salidaroi;

}
```

Error.

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x
>   + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows) in cv::Mat::Mat(const cv::Mat&, const Rect&),
>   file
>   /hdd2/buildbot/slaves/slave_ardbeg1/50-SDK/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp,
>   line 323

Comment: si su imagen original tiene canales de color, es posible que su error se deba precisamente a lo que comenta de que no son del mismo tamaño de ahi el error -> `Assertion failed` sumado a esto otro -> `modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 323` que indica un error de tamaño en Mat. Saludos

Comment: si pero como puedo saber el tamaño de la camara o como puedo hacer que los dos tengan el mismo tamaño?